# Debian 9 iptables device not visible on network

Tags: debian, iptables

I'm trying to secure my server. It is a Debian 9 image for Rock64 arm device.
I changed successfully my ssh port (no problems) and now I want to use a minimal iptables protection for the server, so I'm putting [this rules](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables) into action.
In those rules I have changed my ssh --dport from 22 to my changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config port. I rebooted and can't find the server nor connected to it. I can't figure out what is wrong with such a simple configuration. I believe that my server can't get an ip.
NOTE: one thing to note is that my router assigns a static ip based on a mac address that my server has (maybe iptables is blocking that router mac address discovery)

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I would advise writing the full rules here as they were applied, and not leaving a link. The linked rules also seem done to a server with a static IP address and not getting it via DHCP. (tb sou do Porto)

Comment: Thank you @RuiFRibeiro . So the problem is that the rules may be blocking the dhcp? (Gostava de conectar contigo, vai à minha página dan.mine.bz e deixa-me uma mensagem se quiseres ;) )

Comment: Can you access the system at all now?

Comment: I suspect the problem are the rules. As for having an ARM, I would got a RS232 cable for those situations where you cannot reach it.  https://www.aliexpress.com/item/USB-To-RS232-TTL-UART-PL2303HX-Auto-Converter-USB-to-COM-Cable-Adapter-dec31/32584422172.html

Comment: @HaukeLaging not through ssh. I have to pick up my server sd card and put it in my pc. Why?

Comment: Deactivate the iptables rules and see if you can get in...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I could before so probably will connect now again. What should I do after disabling the iptables?

Comment: Boot and do ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The firewall rules you are using are written for a server with a fixed IP address.

As you are using DHCP, you have to allow it through via iptables.

As such, I would place the additional rule before the accept 80/TCP rule:

```
-I INPUT -p udp --dport 67:68 --sport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
```

From [iptables Tutorial - Letting DHCP requests through iptables](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x6316.html)

> First of all, we should know that DHCP works over the UDP protocol.
>   (...)  To make the rule a bit more specific, we only allow the actual
>   UDP ports used by DHCP, which should be ports 67 and 68.

Comment: Urray! :) Solved

Comment: @alexandre1985 It is important understanding what you are copying from web pages. I have seen web pages with potential damaging instructions with errors when detailing how to shrink or grow partitions. Congrats on solving your problem.

Comment: didn't understand what (disk) partitions have to do with webpages. Thank you

Comment: ok. I understand that the webpage that you have gave me have non damaging instructions. I know (some bit) of linux. Thank you for the advice

Comment: @alexandre1985 Just an example stressing out it is important to not copy blindly instructions from the Internet at large without studying them . Many things outdated, with errors, or which may or not may fit your specific needs.